# Посоветуйте хороши онлайн учебники или видео-курсы по js

Tags: javascript

Кто знает посоветуйте учебники или видео-курсы по js.А то на ютубе один не может 2 слова склеить другой максимально сложно рассказывает (я новичок ).Спасибо.

Comment: @ZELIBOBA Посмотрите [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/)

Answer (score -2):

Гуглите: **Илья Кантор Javascript** ( можно скачать курсы те, что в шару скинули, но уважайте автора, купите!)

Comment: Еще могу посоветовать книгу Николаса Закаса "javascript для профессиональных веб-разработчиков".

Comment: вопросы с книгами закрываются как дубль на общий со списком. не надо публиковать ответы на такие вопросы. лучше дополнять список

Comment: @Дмытрык аналогично ↑

Answer (score -2):

Хороший способ научиться программировать как можно больше решать задачи. 
Для изучения https://learn.javascript.r . Хороший сайт, сам по нему учил.

Comment: вопросы с книгами закрываются как дубль на общий со списком. не надо публиковать ответы на такие вопросы. лучше дополнять список